# Export all SSF contents to RINEX

Tags: export, rinex, ssf

I used Pathfinder Office 5.60 to export SSF to RINEX. But the RINEX contains only L1 code and carrier data. It does NOT seem to export L2 code and carrier. BTW I use a GeoXH 6000 that also records GLONASS.

Is there a way to get the whole lot of raw L1 and L2 data from SSF into RINEX, so I can post-proccess it in another software?

Answer (score 4):

Bit late for an answer, sorry.  Trimble does not allow users to export from SSF to dual-frequency RINEX.